# Combo/Drop down box on plugin settings page that allows additional options to be added

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I'm not sure what this is called and have not had much success searching for it yet.  In a plugin settings page, I would like a 'combo box' or 'drop down box' that also includes the ability to add an option that is not currently included.  That newly added option would be added to the options in the box from that point on.

Is there such a function within the Settings API or does it need a separate text box that is then added to the options array?

Or a better way altogether?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it dynamically on the page you need javascript. [This tutorial explains how to add a items to a `<select>` box.](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-add-options-html-select/) You would have a textbox, the user would type that information in, when they press a button, that would trigger a JavaScript function like the one in the tutorial. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the tutorial and let you know how I get on. Cheers, K